# Server was unable to process request.Connection was not closed

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, ksoap2

I am new for android and and webservices. I am trying to access the web service . I am using asp.net webservices and doing all these work in asyntask.But it gives me error as

05-14 15:28:20.838: E/Error :(28969): Error on soapPrimitiveData() Server was unable to process request`.The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Here is my code

```
        private String retriveFavrt(String user_id) {

        SoapObject resultstring = null;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_2);


        request.addProperty("user_id", user_id);    
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapenvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         soapenvelope.dotNet = true;                                                      
         soapenvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

          HttpTransportSE httptransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
          httptransport.debug = true;


try {
        httptransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_2, soapenvelope);

        resultstring = (SoapObject) soapenvelope.getResponse();
        result2=resultstring.toString();
        et1.setText(result2);
        System.out.println("result" +result2);

        Log.i("try to retrive the favrt location list of a specific user",           resultstring.toString());
        System.out.println(resultstring);


}
 catch (SocketException ex) {
            et1.setText(ex.getMessage());

    Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}

return result2;

        }
         }
```

Kindly help me to resolve this problem.. Thanks in advance.

This is Error:

```
05-14 16:18:13.705: E/SQLiteDatabase(32568): Error inserting user_id=null
05-14 16:18:24.072: E/Error :(32568): Error on soapPrimitiveData() Server was unable to process request. ---> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
```

Comment: Could you please paste the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I have edited my code @user_CC. Kindly check Error

Comment: Could you please paste URL,NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME_2,SOAP_ACTION_2 ... ?@Faiza

Comment: private String METHOD_NAME_2="GetUserFavouriteLocation";
private String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private String SOAP_ACTION_2 = "http://tempuri.org/GetUserFavouriteLocation";
private static final String URL = "http://ip/LocationBasedTaxiServices/LocationWebService.asmx?WSDL"; @ChiragPatel

Comment: Error in URL Like "Page Not found".please send me correct URL @Faiza

Comment: @ChiragPatel it is not hosted.... its on LAN..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors which you placed in your question the first one As per your error message is that userID is coming up as null can you print the userID and see what is the value coming up?

Also can you share the complete stack trace of the very first exception you get if the above doesn't solves the problem?

Also the second error relates to a server problem Can you check whether you are receiving the request on the server?

Comment: The first error is not related...  I was saving it in SQLLite Data Base but now not working.. 2nd error is strange... Help me out plz @user_CC

Comment: I can't see the call to save the variable in the sqlite database? Anyways your namespace and soapaction variables should start with a "http://"

Comment: Done with "http://" but still stuck on this.... I am not using sqlite database... This is extra piece of code..... @user_CC

Comment: can you access the wsdl url on the phone browser and see if it is accessible?

Comment: Also the error looks like it is coming up from the server so it might be the server crashes when it receives the request